# Bash: Extract cells from output formatted as table

Tags: bash, treetagger

I am using TreeTagger (http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) to extract nouns from a text. My problem is that the output is formatted as such:

```
word    pos     lemma

The     DT      the 
TreeTagger      NP      TreeTagger 
is      VBZ     be 
easy    JJ      easy 
to      TO      to 
use     VB      use
```

with apparently no option to get nouns only ("NP" and "NN"). With bash, how could I get the cells in the first column that have "NP" or "NN" in the second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an awk for this:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^N[PN]$/{print $1}' file

TreeTagger
```

Regex `/^N[PN]$/` will match either `NP` or `NN`

As @Cyrus rightly commented below, you can use alternation in your regex as:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^(NP|NN)$/ {print $1}' file
```

Comment: or `awk '$2 ~ /^(NP|NN)$/ {print $1}' file`

Comment: That's great how do I redirect the nouns to an array instead of a file?

Comment: For array population use: `arr=($(awk '$2 ~ /^N[PN]$/{print $1}' file))`

Comment: yes thanks! I had a problem with your code but it's only because I had changed the IFS separator